# Creating mongodb shard failed

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I want to create a shard on mongodb but it fails. This is the resulting error:

```
> cluster = new ShardingTest({"shards" : 3,"chunksize" : 1 });
Resetting db path '/data/db/test0'
2015-11-23T16:57:05.375+0800 Error: boost::filesystem::create_directory: No such file or directory: "/data/db/test0" at src/mongo/shell/servers.js:575
>
```

I start my mongodb like this:

```
./mongod --dbpath /home/lyndonneu/mongodb/data/db
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please note that we are a community for software developers. Your question, however, is about administration and configuration of MongoDB, which is a topic for database administrators. I nominated your question for migration to https://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: The obvious back-question: *does* that directory exist?